# Visual Basic .net make autosave text

Tags: vb.net

So i'm trying to make auto-saving text boxes in VB for the program..I mean when I add some keywords in text box and i close the program,when i reopen it it should be keywords which i entered before..

I'm rookie at this and i tried to auto-save it by clicking on form-close,it didn't work so i gave up trying on my own

I can provide code which i have tried but i don't think it would help but i started this way

```
Sub savecontrols()
Dim appname as string = application.productname
Savesetting(appname, "controls", "textbox1", textbox1.text)

Savesetting(appname, "controls", "textbox2", textbox2.text)

Savesetting(appname, "controls", "textbox3", textbox3.text)

Msg("Controls saved successfully., vbinfornation,"Controls saved.")

End sub
```

Then under formclosing event calling the sub savecontrols` .

```
Sub to call on form load.

Sub getcontrols()

Dim appname as string = Application.productname

textbox1.text = getsetting(appname,"controls","textbox1", "temp")

textbox2.text = getsetting(appname,"controls","textbox2", "temp")

textbox3.text = getsetting(appname,"controls","textbox3", "temp")

End sub
```

Under formload then calling the sub getcontrols
Thanks

Comment: This doesn't tell us how you're trying to save those texts. Please include implementation for method Savesetting in your question.

Comment: edited the code

Comment: You still havent read [ask], still havent taken the [tour], the first snippet still wont compile and it still isnt clear if you are even using VB.NET - generally looks more like VB6. You also still havent asked a question .  MSDN has numerous articles on working with `My.Settings` you can research

Comment: You don't need any code at all to do this. Get rid of it all. Then, select the control, open the Properties window, expand the `(ApplicationSettings)` node and then add a setting for the `Text` property.  The `Text` property contents will then be automatically saved at shutdown and loaded at startup.

Comment: Try to understand `Events`.Every textbox has an event called `TextChabged`,make use of it..As a sample , use this code in the `TextChange` event : `My.Settings.MyTextBoxSaved = textbox1.Text` .. To retrieve it,make use of the `Load` event of the `Form`/`Widnwo` : `Textbox1.Text = My.Settings.TextBoxSaved`

Comment: solved,thanks for helping